# Inserting rating bar in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View grid=inflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem, parent, false);
         imageView=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_prod);
         imageView.setImageResource(imgId[position]);
         imgoff =(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.offer);
         tv=(TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
         tv.setText(namesArr[position]);
         tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rb=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.grid_rating);
         rb.setRating(rateFArr[position]);
            return grid;
        }
```

I insert a rating bar in the GridView the application is force closed as i use setRating here. This `rateFArr[]` is a float array and when i print the value here am getting it rite. Still when i set it to rating bar its not working out.

Plz do help me fixing this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to set the rating... now i solved it with making my own rating bar with 5 imageview each having the default image as empty star and depending on the rating i get i fill it with half filled star image or full filled star image or leave it as empty. Here is the code i done that...

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View grid=inflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem, parent, false);
     imageView=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_prod);
     imageView.setImageResource(imgId[position]);
     imgoff =(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.offer);
     tv=(TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
     tv.setText(namesArr[position]);
     tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     tv.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 0);
   sta=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    sta1=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    sta2=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    sta3=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    sta4=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    Float rate=rateFArr[position];


   if(rate==5 || rate==4.5)
    {
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        if(rate==4.5)
        {
            sta4.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);
        }
        else
        {
            sta4.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        }
    }
    if(rate==4 || rate==3.5)
    {
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
     if(rate==3.5)
        {
            sta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);
        }
        else
        {
            sta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        }
    }
    if(rate==3 || rate==2.5)
    {
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
       if(rate==2.5)
        {
            sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);
        }
        else
        {
            sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        }
    }
    if(rate==2 || rate==1.5)
    {
    sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
     if(rate==1.5)
        {
            sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);
        }
        else
        {
            sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        }
    }
    if(rate==1 || rate==0.5)
    {
        if(rate==1)
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        else
            sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);

    }
    if(rate>5)
    {
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta4.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
    }

    // rb=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.grid_rating);
     //rb.setRating(rateFArr[position]);
        return grid;
    }
```